# html5 page span element css:left property not working

Tags: css, html

I am trying to set the left and top css properties for a span element. This works fine in HTML4 page but has issues on HTML5 page. The code has been posted on jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/arunn/pxxgtnqf/ which shows the behaviour in HTML5 page. I am posting the code here for HTML4 behaviour.

```
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
    <body>
        <span id='hello' style='position:absolute;top:100px;'>hello</span>
    </body>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        document.getElementById("hello").style.left = 100;
        document.getElementById("hello").style.top = 100;
    </script>
</html>
```

Comment: You need to add `+"px"` after both assignments

Answer (score 0):

Make your left and top values a string including a measurment type like "px".

```
document.getElementById("hello").style.left="100px";
document.getElementById("hello").style.top="100px";
```

[Your fiddle updated](https://jsfiddle.net/pxxgtnqf/1/)